# How to add blank lines in Beamer - block

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, overleaf, block

I am writing a presentation on Overleaf and using Beamer.

Example:

```
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{block}{Bloc title}
    Line one

    Line three
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

However, I'm not able to add the blank line. Adding \\ is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible options

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{block}{Bloc title}
    Line one\\
    \phantom{some text}\\
    Line three
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Bloc title}
    Line one\\
    \vspace{1cm}
    Line three
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you very much Ignasi